# Create columns from values and fill them with data from another column (get_dummies, label/one hot encoding)?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

My dataset looks like this:

```
ID_Patient    Exam_Name              Exam_Result
385sdjhf76    Hemogram - Platelets   8487 u.p
385sdjhf76    Urine - Color          dark yellow
385sdjhf76    COVID-19 PCR           Detected
...
```

The Covid-19 exam result will be my target and the other exams my features. What I wanna do includes create a column for each exam and fill that with the value in column Exam_Result. This transformation will reduce the rows of my dataset and should make it look like this:

```
ID_Patient    Hemogram - Platelets   Urine - Color    COVID-19 PCR
385sdjhf76    8487 u.p               dark yellow      Detected  
490dshfj76    374 u.p                Nan              Not detected
387sshhf88    ...                    ...              ...
```

I have already created the binary column for each exam using **get_dummies** but I couldn't replace the 1's for the value in Exam_Result. Any ideas of how can I make this tranformation?

Comment: could you post sample dataset to reproduce the quetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

I will generate some dummy data for a quick example:

```py
data = {'ID_Patient':[1] * 4 + [2] * 4, 
        'Exam_Name':[f'exam {i}' for i in range(4)] * 2, 
        'Exam_Result':[f'result {i}' for i in range(8)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df` now looks like this:

```
   ID_Patient Exam_Name Exam_Result
0           1    exam 0    result 0
1           1    exam 1    result 1
2           1    exam 2    result 2
3           1    exam 3    result 3
4           2    exam 0    result 4
5           2    exam 1    result 5
6           2    exam 2    result 6
7           2    exam 3    result 7
```

let's pivot:

```py
df = df.pivot(index='ID_Patient', columns='Exam_Name', values='Exam_Result')
```

`df` now looks like this:

```
Exam_Name     exam 0    exam 1    exam 2    exam 3
ID_Patient                                        
1           result 0  result 1  result 2  result 3
2           result 4  result 5  result 6  result 7
```

and in case you don't want the multi-index:

```py
df = df.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

and now `df` looks like this:

```
   ID_Patient    exam 0    exam 1    exam 2    exam 3
0           1  result 0  result 1  result 2  result 3
1           2  result 4  result 5  result 6  result 7
```

Comment: I got an error using the pivot() => ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.
What column those duplicate entries refer?

Comment: I've searched more about pivot() and I added aggfunc=','.join as a last paramer and it works! Thank u for your answer, it was really helpful!